# Returning rows that have more than one unique value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select customer_id, currency, price
from sales_table

customer_id   currency  price
1001            CHF       50
1001            EUR       35
1002            EUR       40
1003            AUD       25
```

I have hundreds of thousands of transactions in the table.
How can I do a select clause that only returns the customers who have paid in two different currencies?
In this case, the select statement should return customer_id 1001.

Comment: thinking of using a having clause, but am not sure how to move from there

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING count(distinct currency) > 1

Comment: why count distinct instead of count(currency) in this case?

Comment: you need DISTINCT because otherwise if you simply made 2 payments in EUR for example, that would also show up

Comment: You could add the row (1003, AUD, 10) to your sample data, to improve it, and ensure better quality answers.

Comment: got it, thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select customer_id
from sales_table
group by customer_id
HAVING count(distinct currency) = 2 // or >1 or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select customer_id
from
(
    select customer_id, currency
    from sales_table
    group by customer_id, currency
) t
group by customer_id
having count(customer_id) > 1;
```

You can test it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e729c96398eea3bf9880bb9756cc8e7)